# How to delete all todos items on Delete all button in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a todos list below

```
 constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={
            todos: [{title:'Apple',edit:false},{title:'Banana',edit:false}],
            value : ''
        }
    }
```

and delete button function is

```
delte_all = () => {
        this.state.todos = '';
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos
        })
    }
```

and delete button

```
<button onClick={this.delte_all}>Delete All</button>
```

but its showing error on map function which I don't understand I want to delete all the todos item in  easy way

Comment: How about `this.setState({ todos: [] })` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
this.setState({
    todos: []
})
```

Remember that you shouldn't mutate `state` object directly. you should always use `setState` function to change the state.